# Trying to mock patch a function, but getting PIL\\Image.py'> does not have the attribute 'save'

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I am using pytest-mock, but the exception being thrown is from the mock.patch code, I have verified that the same errot occurs if I use the `@mock.patch` decorator syntax.

MRE (ensure you have pytest and pytest-mock installed, no need to import anything):

```
def test_image(mocker):
    mocker.patch("PIL.Image.save")
```

Now run pytest on this module.

Error:

```
E           AttributeError: <module 'PIL.Image' from 'c:\\users\\...\\site-packages\\PIL\\Image.py'> does not have the attribute 'save'
```

I can see clearly that Image.py does contain a *function* called save, but are functions not considered attributes? I've never heard that word used for the contents of a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save` is an instance method of [`PIL.Image.Image` class](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/8.3.2/src/PIL/Image.py#L508) and not `PIL.Image` module.

You should implement the patch as:

```py
def test_image(mocker):
    mocker.patch("PIL.Image.Image.save")
```

If you need to make assertions that the `save` method is invoked on  the `Image` instance, you need a *name* that is bound to the mock.
You can implement that by mocking the `Image` class and binding a `Mock` instance to its `save` method . For example,

```py
def test_image(mocker):
    # prepare
    klass = mocker.patch("PIL.Image.Image")
    instance = klass.return_value
    instance.save = mocker.Mock() 
    
    # act
    # Do operation that invokes save method on `Image` instance

    # test
    instance.save.assert_called()
```

Comment: I'd completely missed that this was a method rather than a bare function thanks. One thing I'm still a little confused on is how I now refer to the patched method in assertions. PIL.Image.Image.save.assert_not_called() seems to work, but means I have to import PIL to my test module which seems a bit odd since I didn't need that import to patch it out.

Comment: I have updated my response to provide an example for how you could implement that and keep your test implementation free from unnecessary imports.

Comment: Thanks again, I was actually able to simplify your example and simply assign a name to `mocker.patch("PIL.Image.Image.save")` then assert on that. This helped me as it is both shorter and avoids patching the whole class which would have broken another part of the test.